# Q: Istio rewrite

Tags: istio

I have one ingress gateway on : http://kubernetes.docker.internal

3 pods frontend, orders and documents
I want to route all requests to http://kubernetes.docker.internal/ to be redirected to frontend
and all requests to http://kubernetes.docker.internal/api/public/documents/ to the documents pod to http://documents.adventureworks.svc.cluster.local/api/

e.g. http://kubernetes.docker.internal/api/public/documents/system/live -> http://documents.adventureworks.svc.cluster.local/api/

The rewrite does not seem to be executed on the sidecar

Virtual service definition

```yaml
kind: VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: documents
  namespace: adventureworks
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/adventureworks/virtualservices/documents
  uid: 76dece7e-8c27-4b33-90c5-cf64111f4af9
  resourceVersion: '461248'
  generation: 2
  creationTimestamp: '2020-04-03T18:52:36Z'
spec:
  hosts:
    - kubernetes.docker.internal
  gateways:
    - public-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - rewrite:
            uri: /api/
          uri:
            prefix: /api/public/documents/
      route:
        - destination:
            host: documents
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your app correctly then everything should worked just fine.

I have tested istio [bookinfo app](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/)

Specifically the part with [virtual service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.5/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml).

I changed

```
- uri:
    prefix: /api/v1/products
```

to

```
- uri:
    prefix: /api
rewrite:
  uri: /api/v1/products
```

and it worked just fine, so I think it's more your server configuration than istio itself.

---

I see you have [gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) which is already deployed, if it´s not in the same namespace as virtual service, you should add it like in below example.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: some-config-namespace
```

Check the `spec.gateways` section

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-Mongo
  namespace: bookinfo-namespace
spec:
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway # can omit the namespace if gateway is in same
                                       namespace as virtual service.
```